# Touchpad not working occasionally after boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, touchpad

Occasionally when I boot into Ubuntu, touchpad isn't responding at all. I basically have to shutdown and boot again in order to make it work (a reboot won't fix it, have to shutdown).

I've tried different distros too (Fedora, Manjaro) but encounter the same issue.

When it happens, `libinput list-devices` won't recognize the touchpad. Also, running `dmesg` gives the following error which might be related to this:

```
i2c_designware i2c_designware.1: controller timed out
```

The previous message doesn't appear when the touchpad works after boot.

Any idea how to solve this?

Currently I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on Lenovo Yoga and dual-booting with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

There are conflicting devices, try the following:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 

sudo apt autoremove   chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

etc.

Comment: It would be good if you could explain how these commands would help with this - particularly removing those packages